# Does PHP allow getter calling in other functions/methods?

Tags: php, function, exception

So I have getter and I want to call it in __toString() method, but when I echo object, it says that __toString must not trow an exception. So I'm wondering if it is allowed, and if it is, what is wrong with my syntax?

```
private $price;
private $title;

public function getPrice(){
    return $this->price;
}

public function getTitle(){
    return $this->title;
}

public function __toString(){
    return "Price: " . getPrice() . "; Title: " . getTitle(); 
}
```

Comment: You forget about `$this` : `$this->getPrice()` but you don't need to use getter inside class.

Comment: Oh, ok. I'm comming from Java, there you use this in getter, and later call on getter. So it is better practice if I just use $this->price, instead of $this->getPrice() in PHP?

Comment: It's not about php, getter allows you to access private property from outside of class, so in this case you just don't need to use getter.

Comment: Ok, thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the short answer is, it's really up to you.

Personally, I would avoid accessing a vanilla `getter` inside your `__toString()` method. 
 Purely because if someone else changes the method interface, it could change the output and it might not be obvious that it would break the `__toString` method.  (Also, it's (infinitesimally) slower, and my OCD wouldn't allow it :D)

However, if your `getter` has any other logic in it (implying that it's not just to access the raw class property), then you might still have to access the method.  If that was the case I'd make sure that its type-hinted to return a string (in php7) so you can be sure that the overall interface of that method is predictable.

```
public function getPrice(): string
{
    // some fancy logic that makes it a complex getter...
    $price = $this->someLogic($this->price);

    return $price;
}
```